# need help listing a top 5 hangman c#

Tags: c#

I am coding hangman game where in every guess the user gets a point. I'm trying to list a top 5 players of the game each time restart button is clicked. For example if highscore was 2 and player reach 3 his name should be shown in a label. I'm taking the name for a player from login/signup form  and I need it to be sorted  in a txt file  .

```
public static void New_Score(int score, string name)
{
    List<string> scoreList;
    if (File.Exists("scores")) 
        scoreList = File.ReadAllLines("scores").ToList();
    else
        scoreList = new List<string>();
    scoreList.Add(name + " " + score.ToString());
    var sortedScoreList = scoreList.OrderByDescending(ss => int.Parse(ss.Substring(ss.LastIndexOf(" ") + 1)));
    File.WriteAllLines("scores", sortedScoreList.ToArray());
}
```

// its in a method class calling it in form4 ( `Methods.New_Score(User.score, Methods.displayName);`
then when he click restart :

```
 List<string> scoreList = File.ReadAllLines("scores").ToList();
    label8.Text = string.Join("\n", scoreList);
```

Output I am getting:

1. sam 3
2. ram 2
3. jad7

How I want output to be:

1. jad 7
2. sam 3
3. ram 2

So then I can show it in a label like that pls any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note the existence of [`SortedList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedlist-2). I.e. you don't have to do all sorting yourself.

Answer (score 0):

maybe missing 'space' in jad7 is a problem: jad 7, since You're searching the score by looking for the last 'space' in the string, try to look at the very last symbol instead.

Or use dedicated class:

```
using System.Text.Json;

var list = new List<Player>
{
    new Player() {Name = "P1", Score = 1},
    new Player() {Name = "P2", Score = 7},
    new Player() { Name = "P3", Score = 2 }
};

WriteFile.Write(list);
var savedList = ReadFile.Read();

foreach(var p in savedList.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Score))
    Console.WriteLine(p.ToString());

public static class WriteFile
{
    public static void Write(IEnumerable<Player> players)
    {
        var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(players);
        File.WriteAllText("scores.txt",json);
        
    }
}

public static class ReadFile
{
    public static IEnumerable<Player> Read()
    {
        var json = File.ReadAllText("scores.txt");
        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IEnumerable<Player>>(json);
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class Player
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Name} {Score}";
    }
}
```

Comment: no there is space i forgot to add it

Comment: also, make sure there is no space at the end of the string. You could then trim it or use some special character instead of space.

Comment: no worries :-) I posted full solution, slightly cleaner I think, if not good we'll dump it

Comment: thank you for the solution but man we didnt leatn json ik making ur life hard but if you have a more simpler way would appreciate if you want text me in discord so i can send you the project btw somebody told me to split the file then sort the numbers but dk how

Comment: Jadh9 #1629 thats ma discord